# Calling a class method in python

Tags: python, methods

I'm looking to call a method in python from a different class like so:

```
class foo():
    def bar(name):
        return 'hello %s' % name

def hello(name):
    a = foo().bar(name)
    return a
```

Where hello('world') would return 'Hello World'. I'm aware I've done something wrong here, does anyone know what it is? I think it might be the way I'm handling the classes but I haven't got my head around it yet.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, I think there is some syntax wrong in your code,

Comment: We're on 2.5, not a syntax problem it was the 'self' issue as answered about 4 times below ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In Python, non-static methods explicitly take `self` as their first argument.**

`foo.bar()` either needs to be a static method:

```
class foo():
    @staticmethod
    def bar(name):
        return 'hello %s' % name
```

or has to take `self` as its first argument:

```
class foo():
    def bar(self, name):
        return 'hello %s' % name
```

What happens is that in your code, `name` gets interpreted as the `self` parameter (which just happens to be called something else). When you call `foo().bar(name)`, Python tries to pass two arguments (`self` and `name`) to `foo.bar()`, but the method only takes one.

Comment: Thanks, I've only done minimal python in the past! Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the instance parameter in your method definition:

```
class foo():
    def bar(self, name):
        return 'hello %s' % name
```

or if you don't intend to use any part of the `foo` instance declare the method as a static method.  There's a nice explanation between the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python).

Answer (score 3):

If it's supposed to be a class method, then you should have used the [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator and a `cls` argument to `bar`. But that makes no sense in this case, so you might have wanted a [`staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) instead.

Comment: And a `classmethod` has the class (usually called `cls`) as first parameter, so you'd have to add that too.

Answer (score 3):

You missed out the instance parameter, usually named `self`:

```
class foo():
    def bar(self, name):
        return 'hello %s' % name
```